# Pourquoi : À la une ?

Tags: usage, nombres, articles, contractions

Pourquoi dit-on, en parlant de la première page du journal:

> À la une.

et non pas

> À l'une

Alors que l'on dit :

> À l'unité.
>   À l'une ou à l'autre.
>   ...

Comment: Merci pour le vote négatif, on peut savoir pourquoi ?

Comment: Un de perdu, dix-sept de retrouvés...

Comment: Vingt-deux, même !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Un* ou *une*, quand il s'agit de l'ordinal, ne font jamais liaison avec ce qui précède. Je pense que la principale raison est la différentiation avec le pronom ou l'article indéfini, ou même la substantivation de l'adjectif.
Quelques examples :

- « miser sur le un », et non « miser sur l'un » où *un* est interprété comme un pronom ;
- « trente-et-un » sans liaison entre *et* et *un* ;
- « le un » est un ordinal, « l'Un » réfère à une unité supérieure ;
- « n'être qu'un » ou « ne faire qu'un » ne sont pas des exceptions, plutôt des locutions.

J'espère que le hiatus de *la une* te paraît plus naturel.

Comment: Si je ne me trompe pas on ne fait jamais la liaison entre *et* et *un*.

Comment: C'est vrai, je ne peux pas le nier ; ce qui rend l'exemple de 31 non moins correct, mais moins pertinent.

Comment: Comment pourrait-on faire une liaison entre *et* et *un* ?  Exemple ?

Comment: Rien ne t'empêche de prononcer *étain*, mais @StéphaneGimenez remarquait que l'on ne fait jamais cette liaison, quelque soit la valeur grammaticale de *un*.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette réponse très intéressante.

Comment: Il semble qu'on ne fait jamais de liaison après *et* en général, pas juste avec *un*. Un contre-exemple, quelqu'un ?

Answer (score -1):

Il manque le mot page mais on comprend la page une.