# « Âge de un an » ou « âge d'un an » ?

Tags: grammaire, nombres, élision

Pourquoi on dit « je suis venu dans cette ville à l'âge de un an » et pas « à l'âge d'un an » ?

Comment: Je ne saurais pas mieux répondre que ce lien le fait déjà: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3633

Comment: Bienvenue sur Stackexchange. Cette question manque de précisions, il faudrait donner une référence, dire quelles recherches vous avez faites confirmant  l'affirmation qu'« on ne dit pas à l'âge d'un an ». La lecture du [Help Centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help) pourrait vous aider à poser la question.

Comment: Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/pourquoi-%C3%80-la-une/2449#2449

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pourquoi : À la une ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/pourquoi-%c3%80-la-une)

Answer (score 7):

En français, on ne fait – sauf dans de rares expressions anciennes figées – ni élision ni liaison devant un numéral ordinal ou cardinal commençant par une voyelle. Cela est valable pour les nombres « huit », « onze » et « un »  : *Il est âgé de huit ans* et non *d'huit ans*. *Je suis le onzième sur la liste*.
Dans le cas de « un », il faut donc bien distinguer le numéral de l'article indéfini qui, lui, s'élide de manière classique. Dans ce dernier cas, le mot an est d'ailleurs souvent remplacé par « année ».
— *D'un an sur l'autre, la situation se dégrade.*
— *Il est âgé de un an*.
On comprend mieux cela dans d'autres tournures : *J'habite le un de la rue Vidal* (ordinal), *compter de un à cent* (cardinal), etc.

Comment: This is a really good answer, and I learned something even as a native, but I think it would deserve a summary in simpler French for all the non-native people visiting this forum, before or after the existing text

Comment: @Cédric Van Rompay : merci de votre remarque. Il est néanmoins difficile de résumer des détails. J'y pense pour d'autres sujets.

Answer (score -2):

On ne dit pas 'à l'âge de un an', mais bien 'à l'âge d'un an'. l'élision évite le son "euin" jugé malsonnant...de même qu'on ne doit pas dire "la ville de Le Mans", mais bien la ville du Mans.

Comment: Effectivement, pour Le Mans, il n'y a pas d'hésitation mais il semble que ce soit un cas différent. Les attestations de "à l'âge de un an" et de "à l'âge d'un an" sur Google sont comparables et les deux prononciations semblent relativement courantes... Le mot *un* est coutumier de ce type de variation : **d'un** côté, il élide le *e* de *de*, **le *un*** mais pas le *e* de *le* juste ici...